# Why doesn't the string take up the entire width of the container

Tags: bootstrap-5

Angular Project.
I'm trying to place other elements in the Navbar Bootstrap-5 element.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid border">
    <div class="row border">
      <div class="col-2">
        col-1
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        col-2
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        col-3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: result]

The figure shows that the container occupies the entire width of the screen, and the line in this content is only a small part.
Why doesn't the string take up the entire width of the content, as shown in the Bootstrap examples?

Comment: What `string` are you referring to?

Comment: <div class="row border">

Comment: Do you want the output same as the figure shared by you?

Comment: no, I want it to be the full width of the screen